# Avoiding application reload through Gunicorn and Flask

Tags: debugging, flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

My application is reloading due to Werkseug's reload on code change feature. I would like to disable this, in production I am running Gunicorn.

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 \
  --workers 12 \
  --log-level "${LOGGING_LEVEL}" \
  --preload "wsgi:create_app('${FLASK_ENV:-development}')"
  --timeout 240
```

I know running `"flask run --no-reload"` will disable the reload, but how would this be used with Gunicorn?

Answer (score 0):

I think that flask activates auto reload based on its environment.

Maybe change `FLASK_ENV:-development` to `FLASK_ENV:-production`, or just remove it from your command.